# Spring framework Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, servlets

I have some simple spring code
my controller:

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo.mvc;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.StringTrimmerEditor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {

    // add an initbinder ... to convert trim input strings
    // remove leading and trailing whitespace
    // resolve issue for our validation

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {

        StringTrimmerEditor stringTrimmerEditor = new StringTrimmerEditor(true);

        dataBinder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, stringTrimmerEditor);
    }


    @RequestMapping("/showForm")
    public String showForm(Model theModel) {

        theModel.addAttribute("customer", new Customer());

        return "customer-form";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/processForm")
    public String processForm(
            @Valid @ModelAttribute("customer") Customer theCustomer,
            BindingResult theBindingResult) {

        System.out.println("Last name: |" + theCustomer.getLastName() + "|");

        if (theBindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "customer-form";
        }
        else {
            return "customer-confirmation";
        }
    }
}
```

my jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Customer Registration Form</title>

    <style>
        .error {color:red}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<i>Fill out the form. Asterisk (*) means required.</i>
<br><br>

    <form:form action="processForm" modelAttribute="customer">

        First name: <form:input path="firstName" />

        <br><br>

        Last name (*): <form:input path="lastName" />
        <form:errors path="lastName" cssClass="error" />

        <br><br>

        Free passes  (*): <form:input path="freePasses" />
        <form:errors path="freePasses" cssClass="error" />

        <br><br>

        Postal Code: <form:input path="postalCode" />
        <form:errors path="postalCode" cssClass="error" />

        <br><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

    </form:form>

</body>

</html>
```

and my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <display-name>spring-mvc-demo</display-name>

    <!-- Spring MVC Configs -->

    <!-- Step 1: Configure Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Step 2: Set up URL mapping for Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

stacktrace:

```
Dec 06, 2017 11:43:25 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ELManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1710)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:758)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:676)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:642)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:690)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:558)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:499)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:172)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1182)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1072)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5362)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5660)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1690)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ELManager
    at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.buildExpressionFactory(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.<init>(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getDefaultMessageInterpolator(ConfigurationImpl.java:461)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:267)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(OptionalValidatorFactoryBean.java:40)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.el.ELManager
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
    ... 35 more

Dec 06, 2017 11:43:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ELManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1710)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:758)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:676)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:642)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:690)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:558)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:499)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:172)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1182)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1072)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5362)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5660)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1690)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ELManager
    at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.buildExpressionFactory(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.<init>(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getDefaultMessageInterpolator(ConfigurationImpl.java:461)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:267)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(OptionalValidatorFactoryBean.java:40)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.el.ELManager
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
    ... 35 more

Dec 06, 2017 11:43:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [dispatcher] in web application [/spring-mvc-demo] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.el.ELManager
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
    at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.buildExpressionFactory(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.<init>(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.getDefaultMessageInterpolator(ConfigurationImpl.java:461)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:267)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(OptionalValidatorFactoryBean.java:40)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:758)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:676)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:642)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:690)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:558)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:499)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:172)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1269)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1182)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1072)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5362)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5660)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1690)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Dec 06, 2017 11:43:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Dec 06, 2017 11:43:25 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Dec 06, 2017 11:43:25 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3248 ms
Dec 06, 2017 11:43:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
Dec 06, 2017 11:43:26 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
Dec 06, 2017 11:43:26 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Wed Dec 06 23:43:26 EST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
Dec 06, 2017 11:43:26 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml]
Dec 06, 2017 11:43:26 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry register
INFO: Mapped "{[/customer/showForm]}" onto public java.lang.String com.luv2code.springdemo.mvc.CustomerController.showForm(org.springframework.ui.Model)
Dec 06, 2017 11:43:26 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry register
INFO: Mapped "{[/customer/processForm]}" onto public java.lang.String com.luv2code.springdemo.mvc.CustomerController.processForm(com.luv2code.springdemo.mvc.Customer,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)
Dec 06, 2017 11:43:26 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry register
INFO: Mapped "{[/]}" onto public java.lang.String com.luv2code.springdemo.mvc.HomeController.showPage()
Dec 06, 2017 11:43:26 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ELManager
```

but when I run on tomcat, it shows "HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception", and description "description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request."  Actually I tried some easy spring code earlier today, it works. And this time I tried to use validation api and copy some hibernate files to lib, but failed. Anyone could help me out? Thanks!

Comment: can you provide the full stacktrace?

Comment: Are using spring boot or spring?

Comment: @Vinayagam.D it is spring MVC framework

Comment: @saw303 I have updated the stacktrace

Comment: actually I think it is some validation stuff, cause before I use validation api, it works just fine.

Comment: Which version of Tomcat are you using?

Comment: Can you share pom.xml, hoping its a maven project? If not, share jars list on classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells you that to use the ValidationApi Spring need the class [javax.el.ELManager](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/el/ELManager.html), which is part of the Java EL spec since the version 3.0.

Tomcat provide a `el-api.jar` that you'll find in the `tomcat_home/lib` that is the implementation of that spec, but Tomcat older version than 8.X doesn't provide the 3.0 version of the El spec ([you can check see that here](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html)).

If you are not in the good version of tomcat try to upgrade it and see if it works.

Comment: You are right, it is because of old version of tomcat, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed some information in **web.xml** file

```
<web-app>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
</webapp>
```

Comment: after I add these code, its error becomes 404 from 500

Comment: for 404,there is no error trace,just "description The requested resource is not available.". For the 500, I have posted in the problem description. I think it is some validation stuff problem.

Comment: you are using maven ? make sure you have el expression jars in your project classpath.